# Need help: getting a Bootstrap email contact form to work from HTML/PHP code

Tags: contact-form

I am setting up a blog and have a contact form page (standard bootstrap blog template)

I have everything uploaded onto my host - hostgator, but I can't manage to get the contact form to send an email out properly.

I have tried both an external email account and an account on the same domain name with no luck.

Here is the original html source for the contact page from bootstrap: https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-clean-blog/blob/gh-pages/contact.html

and the original source for the contact_me.php: https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-clean-blog/blob/gh-pages/mail/contact_me.php

Is there a setting I need to change from the hostgator cpanel or something in the code I'm missing?

Edit: Here is my domain if you want to view the source I have in place: 
www.decentralizeblog.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made bit changes to the form 
you have not used certain attributes in your form

link **method**, **action** and **name** attribute in text field

```
            <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" action="mailer.php" method="post" novalidate>
                <div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row control-group">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Message</label>
                        <textarea rows="5" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="success"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a problem with your code, have you checked that your hostgator plan supports the php `mail()` function? Some plans (I know from experience) have this disabled as an incentive for you to upgrade.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Just checked with their livechat and my plan supports the function. So it's gotta be an issue with the code.